# How can I set the value in a textbox on form load?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I tried for setting the textbox values but it doesn't seem to be working. I want the textboxes to have the values in them when the page loads. the function is within the script tag.

```
function setMSRP()
        {
            var MSRP = "$29,120.00";
            var destinationCharge = "$875.00";
            var rebate = "-$10,000.00";
            var taxes = "6%"
            var titlesAndFees = "$209.00";
            document.getElementById("txtMSRP").value = MSRP;
            document.getElementById("txtDestinationCharge").value = destinationCharge;
            document.getElementById("txtRebates").value = rebate;
            document.getElementById("txtTaxes").value = taxes;
            document.getElementById("txtElectricTitleAndFees").value = titlesAndFees;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setMSRP()">
    <form>
        <h1>Calculate Focus Price</h1>
        <hr/>
        <label for="txtMSRP">MSRP:</label>
        <input autofocus id="txtMSRP" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="txtDestinationCharge">Destination Charge:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtDestinationCharge" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="txtRebates">Rebates:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtRebates" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="txtTaxes">Taxes:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtTaxes" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="txtElectricTitleAndFees">Electric Title and Fees:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtElectricTitleAndFees" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="btnCalculateTotal" onclick="calcTotal()" 
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in code. Look at the modified example below:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      function setMSRP() {
        var MSRP = "$29,120.00";
        var destinationCharge = "$875.00";
        var rebate = "-$10,000.00";
        var taxes = "6%"
        var titlesAndFees = "$209.00";
        document.getElementById("txtMSRP").value = MSRP;
        document.getElementById("txtDestinationCharge").value = destinationCharge;
        document.getElementById("txtRebates").value = rebate;
        document.getElementById("txtTaxes").value = taxes;
        document.getElementById("txtElectricTitleAndFees").value = titlesAndFees;
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="setMSRP()">
    <form>
      <h1>Calculate Focus Price</h1>
      <hr/>
      <label for="txtMSRP">MSRP:</label>
      <input autofocus id="txtMSRP" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
      <br/>
      <label for="txtDestinationCharge">Destination Charge:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtDestinationCharge" readonly="readonly" />
      <br/>
      <label for="txtRebates">Rebates:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtRebates" readonly="readonly" />
      <br/>
      <label for="txtTaxes">Taxes:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtTaxes" readonly="readonly" />
      <br/>
      <label for="txtElectricTitleAndFees">Electric Title and Fees:</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtElectricTitleAndFees" readonly="readonly" />
      <br/>
      <input type="button" id="btnCalculateTotal" onclick="calcTotal()">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

> I want the textboxes to have the values in them when the page loads.

You don't need JS for this:

```
<input id="txtMSRP" type="text" value="<your_value>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted placeholders inside the `input[type=text]`, simply use

```
var textbox = document.querySelector("#textbox");
textbox.setAttribute("placeholder", "This is the Placeholder");
```

Or use the HTML Attribute to set the value/placeholder:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="Hello" placeholder="Introductory Statement" />
```